# event.preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, preventdefault

I have this simple code here, nothing too advanced.

```
    $("input#send").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: add.php,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

Whever I click on the "send" button, the `event.preventDefault` function doesn't work, and the page loads.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *form* has the submit event, not a button. Plus, an ID should be unique so `tag#id` can just be `#id`.

```
$("#theform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks,  that worked.  May I ask,  I used the click function on the button earlier, but it didn't seem to work that way either? Why is that?

Comment: @Peter Stuart: What exactly do you mean? Putting `click` on the `submit` button works too: http://jsfiddle.net/rKJJU/.

Comment: @PeterStuart I think it's because you didn't put quotes around `add.php`, see my answer below. I agree with @pimvdb's advice about putting the event handler on the form itself, because you can also invoke a form submit with the `enter` key via the keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

You need to bind to the form's `submit` event or to the button's `click` event and call `event.preventDefault()` if you want to stop the form from submitting:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('form').find(':submit').bind('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the submit event is for the **form** element. For an **input[type='button']** you might want to use the click event.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add quotes around `'add.php'`
2. Change the selector in the first line to the `id` attribute of the form which contains `input#send`.

The advantage of handling the `submit()` handler on the form rather than the `click` handler on the input is that some forms can be submitted by pressing the enter key (when the user is focused on one of the form fields). If you don't have an `id` attribute, add one or use a different jQuery selector to target the form tag.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add.php',
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using return false instead

```
$("input#send").submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: add.php,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Should not make a difference.

Comment: `return false` in a jQuery event handler is the same as calling `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: I had tried that, it didn't work because of the ajax. it worked if I put it above the ajax code, but not after it. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using preventDefault I assume that means you do NOT want the default submit action. I would just use a different event instead of using .submit. To me, it's not the submit action that you want to intercept, but rather the click that would normally cause the submit.

```
$('#inputSend').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //the rest
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If both `return false` and `event.stopPropagation()` don't work, try the following method. Using `.on()` will make the submit function accessible. Once you change the `.submit()` to `.on("submit"..)`, you can either use `return false` or `e.stopPropagation()`.

```
$(document).on("submit", "input#send", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: add.php,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });
    return false; });
```